How to correctly measure time complexity of sorting algorithms (Python)
I am trying to capture the wall clock time, CPU time, and complexity of quick, selection, and bubble sorts, but I don't think that my timing outputs at the bottom are correct/plausible. Is there anything in my measurement function that stands out as problematic? My sorts work as intended, so I didn't include them to reduce the length here.
import random
import time

def generate_random_array(size):
    return [random.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(size)]

def bubble_sort(array):
pass

def selection_sort(array):
    pass


def quick_sort(array):
    comparisons = [0]  
    swaps = [0]
    operations_counter = [0]  

    def partition(array):
        if len(array) <= 1:
            return array
        else:
            pivot = array[0]
            less = []
            equal = []
            greater = []
            for x in array:
                comparisons[0] += 1
                operations_counter[0] += 1  
                if x < pivot:
                    less.append(x)
                    operations_counter[0] += 1  
                elif x == pivot:
                    equal.append(x)
                    operations_counter[0] += 1  
                else:
                    greater.append(x)
                    operations_counter[0] += 1  
            operations_counter[0] += 1  
            return partition(less) + equal + partition(greater)

    partition(array)
    return comparisons[0] + swaps[0] + operations_counter[0]



def measure_sorting_time_and_complexity(sort_func, array):
    wall_start = time.time()
    cpu_start = time.process_time()

    complexity = sort_func(array)

    wall_end = time.time()
    cpu_end = time.process_time()

    wall_time = wall_end - wall_start
    cpu_time = (cpu_end - cpu_start) * 1000  # Convert to milliseconds

    return complexity, wall_time, cpu_time


array_sizes = [1000]

for size in array_sizes:
    print(f"Creating an array of size {size}")
    array = generate_random_array(size)

    # Measure and print Bubble Sort performance
    print("*** Bubble Sort ***")
    bubble_complexity, bubble_wall_time, bubble_cpu_time = measure_sorting_time_and_complexity(bubble_sort, array.copy())
    print(f"Execution time: {bubble_cpu_time:.6f} milliseconds")
    print(f"Wallclock time: {bubble_wall_time:.6f} seconds")
    print(f"Complexity: {bubble_complexity}")

    # Measure and print Selection Sort performance
    print("*** Selection Sort ***")
    selection_complexity, selection_wall_time, selection_cpu_time = measure_sorting_time_and_complexity(selection_sort, array.copy())
    print(f"Execution time: {selection_cpu_time:.6f} milliseconds")
    print(f"Wallclock time: {selection_wall_time:.6f} seconds")
    print(f"Complexity: {selection_complexity}")

    # Measure and print Quick Sort performance
    print("*** Quicksort (Recursive) ***")
    quick_complexity, quick_wall_time, quick_cpu_time = measure_sorting_time_and_complexity(quick_sort, array.copy())
    print(f"Execution time: {quick_cpu_time:.6f} milliseconds")
    print(f"Wallclock time: {quick_wall_time:.6f} seconds")
    print(f"Complexity: {quick_complexity}")

Output Below
Creating an array of size 1000
*** Bubble Sort ***
Execution time: 46.875000 milliseconds
Wallclock time: 125.370979 seconds
Complexity: 762366
*** Selection Sort ***
Execution time: 15.625000 milliseconds
Wallclock time: 63.345432 seconds
Complexity: 500500
*** Quicksort (Recursive) ***
Execution time: 0.000000 milliseconds
Wallclock time: 0.000000 seconds
Complexity: 31635


@AndrewYim Hi, while I was running a few test cases I found that the timing outputs for my quick sort seemed weird, even though I know that quick sort is significantly more efficient than the other two sorts. It seemed a bit weird that the wall clock time was 0.0 seconds.

@AndrewYim I just updated the code to include my quick sort implementation. I purposefully don't return the sorted array in any of my three sorts, I only returned what I use to call "complexity" in the outputs.

You should use time.perf_counter() instead of time.time() to time things. Did bubble sort actually take about 2 minutes to run, or is 125 seconds obviously way off?

@Ry- Correct, 125 seconds for the wall time of bubble sort was way off. I used the time.perf_counter() just now, the wall clock times seem to be much more plausible. However, the execution (CPU time) is still at 0.0 for an array size of <= 1000. Maybe this is normal, 0.0 just throws me off.
